# Working with NodeJs serialPort - Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, serial-port, electron

I am trying to get serialport (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) to work on windows so that I can send commands to my serial port and hence open/close the lock.

The serialport was installed via bash.

```
npm install serialport --save-dev
```

Below is the error

```
C:\Users\[...]\electron-with-express\express-app\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:83

Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Below is the page

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var SerialPort = require('serialport');

// check which port is available
//var sp = require('../');


/* GET home page */
router.get('/', function(request, response){

    //sp.list(function(err, ports) {
 // console.log(ports);
//});

 SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
    console.log(port.comName);
    console.log(port.pnpId);
    console.log(port.manufacturer);
  });
});
});

// Important
module.exports = router;
```

The NodeJs app is being run via Electron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Node modules such as `serialport` must be rebuilt to target the specific Electron version you're using, to do so follow the steps documented at http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/

There's also an [open issue](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport/issues/538) covering the topic, so if you get stuck at least read [this comment](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport/issues/538#issuecomment-237641682).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have notice that the issue occurs when i have node.exe in my root folder, which is recommended/required to have  the express app running correctly within electron https://github.com/frankhale/electron-with-express when it is removed serialport works without issue, i have tried rebuild, but its really the node..exe that causing some issues. WOuld there be a way to run the app without node.exe included in the root folder

Comment: @John There's absolutely no need to shove `node.exe` into your app dir, Electron can spawn new Electron processes that act just like a vanilla Node processes. So, if you want to spawn a separate process to run express or what not just use `child_process.fork()` in your Electron app.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Im new to this. Could you elaborate on child_process.fork()? Where would i add that? On the main.js file?

Comment: Yes, you could call `child_process.fork()` from `main.js`, but you could also do it from a renderer process (by replacing [this line](https://github.com/frankhale/electron-with-express/blob/f07e98bff7a53cdc126e5128e5971987afaa70fa/index.html#L61) in `electron-with-express` with `child_process.fork()` you're almost there). I would however urge you to ditch `electron-with-express` due to its GPL3 license.

Comment: with that line added/replace it now says index.html:61 Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

Comment: thank you for all of your help. I have used electron-with-express only as a baseline but it was greatly modified to the point where one cant say its the same, would i still run into licence issues? What would be the alternative?

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind assisting me with this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020525/how-to-run-express-within-electron